# Python says variable is not defined but it is I believe

Tags: python

So im learning python in school but the teacher sucks so thats why im here. I am doing an assignment but the variable decided it didnt want to work even though it was working yesterday

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "food.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(Fore.BLUE + 'You choose ' + sandwich_choice + ' with a price of ' + sandwich_price)
NameError: name 'sandwich_price' is not defined
```

Code that produces the error:

```py
if sandwich_choice_input == 'Chicken Sandwich' or sandwich_choice_input == 'Beef Sandwich' or sandwich_choice_input == 'Tofu Sandwich':
  sandwich_choice = sandwich_choice_input
  chicken = '$5.25'
  beef = '$6.25'
  tofu = '$5.75'
elif sandwich_choice_input == 'Chicken Sandwich':
  sandwich_price = chicken
elif sandwich_choice_input == 'Beef Sandwich':
  sandwich_price = beef
elif sandwich_choice_input == 'Tofu Sandwich':
  sandwich_price = tofu
  
print(Fore.BLUE + 'You choose ' + sandwich_choice + ' with a price of ' + sandwich_price)
```

I tried the variable I tried moving the variable to a db but that didnt work either and I wanted it to put the price of the sandwich which is already pre defined im also extremely new to python so please dont judge

Comment: What if none of you conditions are `True`? There's no `sandwich_price` then.

Comment: Where's the `if`?

Comment: can you share the whole method from `food.py`? This seems to be a partial snippet.

Comment: Be careful about indentation. It matters in Python.

Comment: Please do not add code by posting in a comment. You should instead actually edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that earlier on in your code you're asking, via `input()`, for a variable called `sandwich_choice_input`. The problem with your technique is that it's error prone: It relies on the user typing the answer to this `input()` *exactly* as your three answers (Chicken Sandwich etc.) are spelled. Even a slight typo, such as a missing letter or incorrect capitalisation, will mean no value is assigned to the variable `sandwich_choice`, and your code breaks.

To avoid this problem, you could, for instance, present (with `print()`) the three available choices to the user, numbered 1-3, and the user simply types the number of the desired choice; you would then compare the input against `'1'` etc. rather than against `'Chicken Sandwich'` etc. This would considerably reduce the probability of errors.

Also, the line `elif sandwich_choice_input == 'Chicken Sandwich':` isn't correct; this needs an `if`, not an `elif` (because there is no preceding `if` that the `elif` could be "else" to).

Comment: Changing the elif to if worked for me thanks I am just very confused why elif worked yesterday and not today

Comment: You should understand the meaning of "if" and "elif"

Comment: I don't see how it could have worked with elif. The reason is that before the first elif (that should be an if), there's an if with three alternatives, which are the same as in the three ifs that follow. This means there are two possibilities: 1) The user correctly types in one of these three choices. In that case, the first if is triggered, and none of the three subsequent elifs get executed. 2) The user does not correctly type one of the three choices. Then the first if doesn't get executed, but none of the elifs gets executed either. Either way, "sandwich_price" remains undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do that :

```
  sandwich_choice_input = input("what do you want to eat ?")
  choices = ['Chicken Sandwich', 'Beef Sandwich', 'Tofu Sandwich' ]
  sandwich_choice = ""
  if sandwich_choice_input in choices :
      sandwich_choice = sandwich_choice_input
      chicken = '$5.25'
      beef = '$6.25'
      tofu = '$5.75'
    if sandwich_choice_input == 'Chicken Sandwich':
      sandwich_price = chicken
    elif sandwich_choice_input == 'Beef Sandwich':
      sandwich_price = beef
    elif sandwich_choice_input == 'Tofu Sandwich':
      sandwich_price = tofu
  
    print(Fore.BLUE + 'You choose ' + sandwich_choice + ' with a price of ' + sandwich_price)
  else : print("Sorry, your order is not available")
```